# How to iterate on a file in python where records are multi-line with comma separated fields and the records are delimited by an empty line?

Tags: python, named-entity-extraction

The below dataset consists of sentences wherein every word is labelled individually. I want to split this into two variables to train my model. The records are separated by an empty line and every record spans multiple lines where the word and label are comma separated.

```
how,SW
is,SW
the,SW
weather,WTR
?,.
       # blank line
will,SW
it,SW
rain,RAIN
this,ADJ
weekend,TIME
?,.
```

I want to process this input file to generate the expected output as shown below:

X variable must contain all words of every record as individual lists:

```
[[how, is, the, weather, ?], [will it rain this weekend, ?]]
```

Y variable must contain labels  of every record as individual lists:

```
[[SW, SW, SW, WTR, .], [SW, SW, RAIN, ADJ, TIME, .]]
```

Please suggest. Thank you!

Comment: On one line you have just one word,label pair? Or could be more?

Comment: Does the end of the file also have a blank line?

Comment: Every line contains only one pair of word,label.

Comment: The end of the file can be a blank line. Either way will do, as long as it makes it easier to process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably something like this would work:

```
Xs = []
Ys = []
with open('file.txt', 'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
i = 0
X = []
Y = []
for line in lines:
    line = line.strip()
    if line == "":
        Xs.append(X)
        Ys.append(Y)
        X,Y = [],[]
    else:
        x,y = line.split(",")
        X.append(x)
        Y.append(y)
Xs.append(X)
Ys.append(Y)
print(Xs)
print(Ys)

#[['how', 'is', 'the', 'weather', '?'], ['will', 'it', 'rain', 'this', 'weekend', '?']]
#[['SW', 'SW', 'SW', 'WTR', '.'], ['SW', 'SW', 'RAIN', 'ADJ', 'TIME', '.']]
```

The code basically goes open the file, read all the lines, and iterate through the lines to check if we've finished importing a record (as indicated by an empty line) and act accordingly. `line.strip()` removes all whitespace from the line, so `"\n".strip()` would output `""`.